# Calculating the Jacobian of a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, confidence-interval, deep-learning, jacobian

I'm trying to calculate confidence intervals for a neural network (rather than prediction intervals).  I'm following [this](https://www.esa.espci.fr/sites/www.esa.espci.fr/IMG/pdf/2000conf.pdf) paper, which treats them in the same framework as any parametric (parameter-involving?) nonlinear model (which a neural net basically is).  Calculating these CI's involves computing the Jacobian -- the matrix of partial derivatives of $\hat y$ with respect to the parameters.

In the one-outcome regression case, a neural net with two hidden layers (and no biases, WLOG) is
$$
y = \sigma(\sigma(\mathbf{X\alpha)\beta)\gamma} + \epsilon
$$
where

- $y$ is the $N\times 1$ outcome
- $\mathbf{X}$ is the $N\times P_x$ data
- $\alpha$ is the $P_x \times P_\beta$ first set of weights
- $\beta$ is the $P_\beta \times P_\gamma$ second set of weights
- $\gamma$ is the $P_\gamma \times 1$ final set of weights, linking to $y$
- $\epsilon$ is the mean-zero error
- $\sigma()$ is the activation function

The chain rule gives me the following partial derivatives of the fitted model:
$$ \begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle\frac{\partial\hat y}{\partial \hat\gamma} & = & \sigma(\sigma(\mathbf{X\alpha})\beta) \\
\displaystyle\frac{\partial\hat y}{\partial \hat\beta} & = & \sigma'(\sigma(\mathbf{X\alpha})\beta)\gamma\sigma(\mathbf{X}\alpha) \\
\displaystyle\frac{\partial\hat y}{\partial \hat\alpha} & = & \sigma'(\sigma(\mathbf{X\alpha})\beta)\gamma\sigma'(\mathbf{X}\alpha)\beta \mathbf{X} \end{array}
$$

Now, the matrix dimensions on the above expressions are not conformable, which suggests that vectorizing the Jacobian calculation is not possible. Is this true?

Next, if I need to calculate the partial derivatives parameter-by-parameter, what is the appropriate way to deal with the network structure when evaluating each derivative?

For example, $\alpha_1$ links the $\mathbf{X}_1$ to $\sigma(\mathbf{X\alpha})_1$.  That node in turn links to several different upper nodes.  Let's say that there are $g$ hidden units in the topmost layer.  Should the Jacobian column for $\alpha_1$ include $\displaystyle\sum_g \sigma(\mathbf{X\alpha})_1 \beta_g$ (i.e.: row-wise sum)?  Or would the combination of the $\beta$'s take some other form than a sum?

Likewise, $\hat\alpha_1$ influences $\hat y$ through all of the top layer hidden-units.  So $\hat\alpha_1$'s Jacobian column should also include $\sigma'(\sigma(\mathbf{X\alpha})\beta)\gamma$, treated as a matrix, which evaluates to a $N \times P_\gamma \times P_\gamma \times 1 = N \times 1$ matrix?

$\hat\alpha_1$'s Jacobian column would thus be
$$
\frac{\partial\hat y}{\partial \hat\alpha_1} = \sigma'(\sigma(\mathbf{X\alpha})\beta)\gamma\circ\displaystyle\sum_g\sigma'(\mathbf{X}_1\alpha_1)\beta_g \circ\mathbf{X}_1
$$

Is this correct?
Is there a more efficient way to do this?
Can a general statement be made about how much better the analytical Jacobian would be than one calculated by numerical approximation, for example in the `numDeriv` package in R?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you do not use backpropagation?

Comment: I train the model with backprop.  Is there some way to get a linear taylor expansion of the fitted model from backprop?

Comment: No, but backprop essentially calculates the Jacobian. So if you just backprop using the identity as a loss function, you should get the Jacobian of the outputs wrt the weights.

Comment: @bayerj That's a good idea.  I haven't written my code such that the loss function is a drop-in argument, but if I ever implement such a setup I might do as you suggest.